# Unable to accept vote or delete posts

Tags: support, stack-overflow

Why is it that i am unable to mark as accepted/delete/vote/favourite in any of the posts? (my SO reputation is 219)
could anyone please tell the possible reasons?

Comment: not able to accept answers to or delete my questions and vote up or down answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried clearing your browser cache?